# Viewing Multiple Data Streams From Application

Tags: terminal

I am running latest Ubuntu LTS and wrote an application that interfaces with a machine.  The machine has multiple sensors and several PID loops for temperature control.  The data comes in very fast, about 20 readings/second. During testing I'd like to have access to each of these as separate streams.  That way I can arrange some terminals for a 'master' view of everything that's happening.

My current solution is to just have files for each stream and have the application append the necessary file as a reading is made.  Then I simply enter a command like 'tail -f /tmp/pressure.log' and I'm good to go.

It's throwaway data so I am currently putting them in /tmp so it gets cleared out.  But that's a crapload of writes and the file size could get massive.  Ideally the application would write to something in /dev that I can tail just like I'm doing.

So, what's the best way to have an application stream text that can be viewed in a separate process?  Ideally I'd like to make as few changes to my application as possible.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

The normal UNIX way to stream data from one application to another without saving it permanently is a pipe. In shell:

```
data-producer | data-consumer
```

You can always use named pipes for patterns more complex than a single producer emitting and a single consumer receiving:

```
# Set up the pipes
mkfifo /tmp/pressure.fifo
mkfifo /tmp/temperature.fifo

# Start the emiters
monitor-pressure >/tmp/pressure.fifo
monitor-temperature >/tmp/temperature.fifo

# Take input from multiple places
collect-and-analyse-all-data /tmp/pressure.fifo /tmp/temperature.fifo
```

Pipes (whether regular unnamed or named) have a few downsides in this context:

- Prior to the consumer running or becoming ready to read data, the producer will block, or else the pipe will buffer data up to a point and then block. For a data logger, it may be better to discard data when there's no one listening instead of buffering it or blocking the process. It depends on your application.
- If the consumer stops running or closes the pipe, the producer will get an error trying to write to the pipe. This causes naive programs to abort. It is possible to ignore the error and continue trying until a consumer opens the pipe again (only possible with named pipes) but you have to do more work to make this happen.

UNIX is rich in IPC mechanisms and you can take your pick from a bunch of other ones too:

- temporary files that grow without bound (this sound like what you're doing now)
- temporary files whose data constantly gets replaced with the latest data item. Simple, but fragile in case the consumer does not have time to read a data item before it is replaced.
- temporary files that grow to a point and then get rotated. More work to implement on both the producer and consumer side to get synchronization working right and don't lose data items while the file is being rotated, but quite a good compromise.
- shared memory
- datagram sockets.
- etc...

The last two are hard to do with shell scripting but the last one (datagrams sockets) is at least possible, and made easier if using a programming language like Python.

If you're willing to spend a little bit more time and have some basic networking skills with a language like Python (or Ruby, etc...) then datagram sockets (UNIX or UDP) have a lot going for them. The data is ephemeral so it doesn't consume memory, there is nothing to do to arrange the communication setup between producer and consumer (just send and receive on the right port) and therefore no errors to manage when one or the other crashes or gets restarted, and the producer and consumer can even be remote from each other. The only downside is that the data goes into the bit bucket rather than getting buffered while the consuming application is not running.

Again, what solution you pick will depend on your application.

Comment: I'm a networking gal at heart. Seems it shows through in my promotion of UDP sockets as a solution here :-)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to used named pipes.  Your application could write to the named pipes, and you could monitor the pipes in the same fashion that you're currently doing.  You'd probably want to make your write operations to the pipe non-blocking so that if the pipe fills up it doesn't block the program execution.  Note, however, with that you'd be loosing data that couldn't be written.

See 'mkfifo' for creating named pipes.  You can do it either programmatically with mkfifo(3) or manually with mkfifo(1).